# Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: angular, npm, node-gyp

I'm running npm install on an Angular 5 dotnetcore project pulled down from source tree which is running fine on my work machine, but on my home when I try initial npm install it has the following error. Doesn't mean much to me, and googling hasn't really gotten me anywhere. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection       was established
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1092:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:203:15)
gyp ERR! stack     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Joshu\\Documents\\project\\ProbationProject2\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Joshu\Documents\project\ProbationProject2\ClientApp\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`node-gyp` is a tool that enables compilation of native packages for NodeJS.

[The article "A Comprehensive Guide to Fixing Node-Gyp Issues on Windows"](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/03/27/node-gyp-windows/) has multiple items to try to resolve `node-gyp` issues on Windows.

Do you have the `windows-build-tools` package installed?

If not try their recommendation:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools --vs2015
```